# CodeIgniter Composer "package.json" locations shluld be in application or root folder?

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php

I working with code igniter v3.x and I would like to add some composer packages.

looking at `application/config/config.php` file, it says that will load packages inside application folder

```
| package auto-loader script in application/vendor/autoload.php.
```

However in the codeigniter package it already has a `package.json` that installs packages on root folder.

I suspect that the `package.json` on the root must hold only information about CodeIgniter it self. But I'm not sure.

So I have three options:

1. Create a new `package.json` inside the `application` folder and install packages inside `application`.
2. Modify the `package.json` on the root folder by adding new package and change `autoload.php` location

What is expected from a CodeIgniter Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you take a look at the Codeigniter Documentation you can see there is a Configuration setting called `composer_autoload`. This information can be found [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html).

If you set this `true`, Codeigniter tries to load Composer's autoload.php in the `APPLICATION.'vendor'` folder. If you take a closer look at the [Codeigniter.php](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/CodeIgniter.php#L117) file, you'll see that you can define a directory for this setting too.

So in your case you don't have to change the `package.json` in the root folder because you need one in the application folder, in case you set `composer_autoload` to  `true`, which i would recommend.

By the way if you try to install a package via composer in your application directory, composer asks you if you want to use the one it found on the root folder - just decline that and press `n`.

As you can see in the picture below (i just tried to install the mpdf package).

[image]