# specify multiple resources/packages in composer_autoload

Tags: codeigniter, composer-php

I provided the path in `$config['composer_autoload] = 'vendor/autoload.php';`

then inside the autoload.php file I insert two packages that I need to use:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/phpspreadsheet/composer/autoload_real.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/phptcpdf/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit9d1bd4a6e5194a15c3a7fbbedd5e69dc::getLoader();
return ComposerAutoloaderInitd3643b2c089f2f5cb6ea7ae57abe30b2::getLoader();
```

somehow only phpspreadsheet is being loading and the tcpdf shows Class TCPDF not found.

Please help.

TIA

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52574192/codeigniter-composer-package-json-locations-shluld-be-in-application-or-root-f/52575089#52575089 - try to read that one - maybe you'll understand how composer and CI works

Comment: If the suggested Q&A does not apply, you should [edit] this one to tell us why not.

Comment: still wasn't able to load multiple libraries/ resources even thou for phpspreadsheet and tcpdf. I added the autoload lines of tcpdf to phpspreadsheet but sill the error Class TCPDF not found appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second autoloader initialization is never executed, because of `return` in the previous line. So last line is ignored - no wonder that TCPDF autoloader does not work:

Try something like:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/phpspreadsheet/composer/autoload_real.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/phptcpdf/composer/autoload_real.php';

ComposerAutoloaderInit9d1bd4a6e5194a15c3a7fbbedd5e69dc::getLoader();
ComposerAutoloaderInitd3643b2c089f2f5cb6ea7ae57abe30b2::getLoader();
```

You don't need to return autoloader, calling `getLoader()` is enough to initialize autoloader.

Also note that this weird hash in autoloader class name may change - you should probably include `autoload.php` instead of `autoload_real.php` (if it is available), it may save you a trouble in fixing name after each update.

Comment: Thank you very much! (Thou my PDF shows blank page, thou that will be a different topic) Most instructions shows only how to autoload a single library or by installing composer, but in my case, my composer doesn't work and shows PHP settings error. Including autoload.php may also work as I haven't tried.